# Creating a listview on the homescreen

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the code and this opens a list with the name, but it is in a new window. What I want to do is put this list on the main window. What can I do?

[image]

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

            String []name={"bill","gorg"};

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,name));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
                Object o=this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
                String keybord= o.toString();
                Toast.makeText(this, "you are select "+keybord, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add your listview to where ever you want. That's it. Here YOU have created the new Activity for the listview. Instead drag and drop your listview to your main window.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "main window" do you mean the home screen of an Android device? If that's what you are referring to, it's not exactly possible.  The home screen is an application itself, that can link to other applications which you can see on your "desktop".  If you want to be able to display a list of something, then you could create a widget along with your app and the widget could be displayed on one of the panels of a device's home screen.

If you want to create a widget that can be added to the home screen, check the [widget developer docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)